# How to pass PHP variable that is created after submit to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, variables

I've beens searching for the answer on this one, but so far I couldn't find it. I'm trying to submit a form. After the form is submitted, a message is created. This message should be prepended to a table.

Here are some code snippets:

```
if($ids = $threadMessageObject->insert()){
    $newMessage = '<tr>
                    <td class="dashCellLeft">Test data</td>
                    <td class="dashCellRight">on Test Date</td>
                </tr>';
}
```

The above code is triggered **after** the form is submitted. Normally, I could get the values of the form at the moment the user clicks 'submit'. However, these formfields are generated by someone else's code and I can't change that (which means I can't get the data).

I have a feeling that the problem comes from the fact that PHP is server side, while jQuery is client side.

Now, my jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#threadMessageForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.submit();
        alert("<?php echo($newMessage); ?>");
        var newMessage = '<?php echo $newMessage; ?>';
        if (!newMessage) {
            parent.$('.threadAnswers .dash .dashContent .infoTable').prepend('<tr><td class="dashCellLeft">Test Name</td><td class="dashCellRight">on Test Date</td></tr><tr><td class="dashCellLeft">Random Message!</td><td class="dashCellRight">Respond</td></tr>');
        }
        else {
            parent.$('.threadAnswers .dash .dashContent .infoTable').prepend(newMessage);
        }

    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try using ajax call after form submitted...

Comment: You need to submit the form using ajax, `this.submit();` will submit it the regular way, causing a page reload.

Comment: @jeroen given the fact that the variable `$newMessage` is created after the post is submitted, isn't a regular submit exactly what I want?

Comment: @Spyron10 This is a strange mix of php and javascript that probably won't work, but no, as soon as you submit the form, the page will load the url of the `action` attribute and you will never see anything prepended as on the freshly loaded page there has not been a form submit yet. You need ajax and from the php script you call, you return what you want to prepend later on.

Comment: What if I place the jQuery code within a php if loop that checks if `$newMessage` exists? `if($newMessage){ ?> //jquery code <?php }` Would that work?